# Which is the best approach to add Server Side Rendering on a MERN aplication created with CRA?

Tags: reactjs, express, next.js, server-side-rendering, mern

I have been working on a MERN aplication and I would like to add Server Side Rendering for faster loading times and SEO support. Already checked several tutorials, but not sure if this examples are the best approach as **I am using Create-React-App**.

Some of the tutorials I have been following:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=82tZAPMHfT4

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/server-side-rendering-your-react-app-in-three-simple-steps-7a82b95db82e/

Comment: I would suggest going with Nextjs, they have a bunch of built-in tools and optimization which you have to deal with when trying to create a React SSR by yourself.

Answer (score 2):

First of all I suggest to migrate to frameworks like Next.js, because has a lot of built-in function for SSR. But if you want to have SSR on React application, simplest way is:

**1.** Creating an Express Server and Rendering the App Component

**2.** Configuring webpack, Babel, and npm Scripts

[Best article for this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/react-server-side-rendering)